# React synthetic event returned from onLoad() of <image> element inside <svg> does not have naturalWidth or naturalHeight properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, svg, onload-event

I am using ReactJS. My aim is to trigger some events when an image loads inside an SVG element.

Without SVG element, this code below **works as expected** -

```
function onImageLoad(event) {
   console.log("Event triggered from <img> element", event);
    // AS EXPECTED : Event object has natural width and natural height
  }

return (
      <div>
        <img src={imageName} onLoad={ (event) => onImageLoad(event) }/> 
      </div>
)
```

However, this code **does not work as expected** -

```
function onImageLoad(event) {
    console.log("Event triggered from <image> element", event);
    // UNEXPECTED : Event object does not have natural width or natural height
  }

return (
      <div>
        <svg>
          <image href={imageName} onLoad={ (event) => onImageLoad(event) }/> 
        </svg>
      </div>
)
```

I have tried reading in several places. Its not clear why `<image>` is different from `<img>` for `onLoad()` synthetic event in react.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike [HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement), the [SVGImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGImageElement) interface doesn't expose a `naturalWidth` or `naturalHeight` properties, nor any ways to retrieve the intrinsic size of the inner image by the way.

If you want to get it, the easiest would be to load the image again in an HTML `<img>`, an alternative would be to create an [ImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap) from the `<image>` but not all browsers do support it.

```js
const svgImg = document.querySelector("image");
const getSVGImageSize = async (src) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = src.href.baseVal;
  await img.decode();
  const { width, height } = img;
  return { width, height };
};

getSVGImageSize(svgImg)
  .then(({ width, height }) => console.log("from HTMLImageElement", { width, height }))

// alternative using createImageBitmap,
// not supported in Safari
svgImg.addEventListener("load", e => createImageBitmap(svgImg)
  .then(({ width, height }) => console.log("fom ImageBitmap", { width, height }))
  .catch(console.error)
);
```

```html
<svg>
  <image href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the event.currentTarget, not the event itself

```
<image href={imageName} onLoad={ (event) => onImageLoad(event.currentTarget) }/>
```